# ICS - no internet, but access to network drive possible

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, wi-fi, networking, connection-issues

I've set up wifi on an ICS phone.

I can connect to a network drive in the system, so the connection seems to be OK. However when I try the browser I get the message 'problem loading page'.

I used static IP and I just copied the settings from my laptop that can access internet fine with these settings (of course I used different IP adresses for laptop and phone).

Also e-mail and other apps that need internet connection don't work. If enabled 3G connection works OK.

Apart from the 'problem loading page' message there a no other error notifications.

Maybe a know issue for somebody?

Comment: Looks like you forgot to add DNS or Gateway.

Comment: Did you copy the same IP from the laptop? Or used a different one in the same subnet?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just use DHCP on your router?

Comment: Finally found out the problem. It had to do with the network prefix (an option not present in the setup of the laptop, so I used the default of -24- on the phone). Thank you all for your comments

Comment: @Wilson would you mind to describe your solution in an answer (and accept it when this becomes possible after 2 days), so people can see there's a solution and what it is? Thank you in advance in the name of the community!